# Proof: |detA| = 1 if A is unitary (that is, if $AA^* = I_n).$ Does it make sense?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, determinant

A matrix $A \in Mat(n, \mathbb{F})$ is called *unitary* if $AA^* = I_n,$ where $A^* = \overline{A^T} = \operatorname{conj}(A^T)$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$ (where the complex conjugate is taken for every entry in $A$). Prove that $\left\vert \det{A} \right\vert = 1$ only if $A$ is unitary.

If $A$ is orthogonal, then $AA^* =  I_n$ and $$\det{(AA^*)} = \det{A}\det{A^*} = \det{I_n} = 1.$$ It will be shown that $$\det{A^*} = (\det{A})^*.$$ It is established that for $x, y \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ 
    $$\overline{\lambda} = \lambda \\
 \overline{\lambda x} = \lambda \overline{x} \\
 \overline{\overline{x}} = x \\
 \overline{x+y} = \overline{x} + \overline{y} \\
 \overline{x \cdot y} = \overline{x} \cdot \overline{y} \\$$

Consider the arbitrary $2 \times 2$ matrix $$M = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$$ and its conjugate transpose $$M^* = \begin{pmatrix} \overline{a} & \overline{c} \\ \overline{b} & \overline{d} \end{pmatrix}.$$

As $$\det{M} = a\det{d} - b\det{c} = ad - bc$$ 
and 
$$\det{M^*} = \overline{a} \cdot \overline{\det{d}} - \overline{b} \cdot   
          \overline{\det{c}} \\
         = \overline{a}\overline{d} - \overline{b}\overline{c} \\
         = \overline{a}\overline{d} - \overline{b}\overline{c} \\
         = \overline{ad} - \overline{bc} = \overline{ad - bc},$$
    and $$\overline{\overline{ad - bc}} = ad - bc,$$
    it follows that $$\det{M} = \det{M^T} = \overline{\det{M^*}} = (\det{M^*})^*$$
    and $$\overline{(\det{M})} = (\det{M})^* = \det{\overline{M^T}} = \det{M^*}.$$

Now, suppose the equality holds for any $n \times n$ matrix $M.$ Consider the $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrix $M'.$ By the cofactor expansion of determinants, 
    $$
 \det{M'} = \sum_{j=1}^{n+1} A_{ij} \cdot \operatorname{cof}(A)_{ji} $$

So, given $$\det{M} = \det{M^T}$$ and by the properties of conjugates, 
    $$\overline{\det{M'}} = (\det{M'})^* = \operatorname{conj}{(\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}A_{ij}\cdot\operatorname{cof}(A)_{ji})} \\ 
 =\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\overline{(A_{ij}\cdot\operatorname{cof}(A)_{ji})} \\
 =\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\overline{A_{ij}}\cdot\overline{\operatorname{cof}(A)_{ji}} \\
 =\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\overline{A_{ji}}\cdot\overline{\operatorname{cof}(A)^T_{ji}} \\
 = \det{\overline{(M')^T}} = \det{M'^*}.$$

Hence, by induction, $$\det{A^*} = (\det{A})^*,$$ and therefore $$\det{A}\det{A^*} = (\det{A})(\det{A})^* = 1.$$ Suppose $$\det{A} = x + iy.$$ Therefore, $$(\det{A})^* = x - iy,$$ and $$(\det{A})(\det{A})^* = (x + iy)(x - iy) = x^2 + y^2 = 1.$$ So, $$|\det{A}|^2 = 1$$ and $$\left\vert \det{A} \right\vert \geq 0 \implies \left\vert \det{A} \right\vert = 1.$$

Comment: An easier proof: Note that $\det(A)$ is the product of the eigenvalues of $A$.  Show that all the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$ satisfy $|\lambda| = 1$.  You can see this by letting $v$ be an eigenvector and considering $(Av, Av)$ with $(u,v) = \bar{u}^T \cdot v$.

Comment: Haven't learned about Eigenvalues yet!

Comment: Ah, I see.  You'll presumably get to them very soon then.

Comment: Hey Taylor, does the induction step make sense to you too?

Comment: I haven't looked at it in detail.  It's rather easier to take Aweygan's advice and note that $\det A$ is a polynomial in the entries of $A$.

Comment: But I think the idea looks right.

Comment: Alright, thanks Taylor!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything seems fine.  Since $|\det A|\geq0$, the $-1$ in $\pm1$ doesn't occur.

Comment: Hey Aweygan. What does TL;DR mean?

Comment: Too long; didn't read.

Comment: Haha ok. Thanks for your input!

Comment: If you don't mind, would you take the time to look just at my induction step in the middle of proof (with the summations) to check if it makes sense?

Comment: @RafaelVergnaud Just did.  It looks fine.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot @Aweygan!

Comment: @RafaelVergnaud You're welcome.  Before I go, I have two recommendations.  Firstly, since you seem comfortable with the fact that $\det(M^T)=\det(M)$, just note that $\det(M)$ is a polynomial (with real coefficients) in the entries of $M$. Then recall that conjugation commutes with applying such polynomials.

Comment: Secondly, if you know that $\det(M)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_{n+1}}\text{sign}(\sigma)A_{i\sigma i)$, the proof then doesn't require induction.